# Problems converting this code from c# to VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net

I'm having problems converting following code from c# to VB.NET.
I've tried the online converters but they are all throwing errrors.
Could someone show me the converted VB.NET code.

```
FixedPage page2= new FixedPage();
PageContent page2Content = new PageContent();
((IAddChild)page2Content).AddChild(page2);
```

Comment: That's interesting. Did you have a question?

Comment: http://converter.telerik.com handles it fine. If that gives you errors, then it is not the result of the language conversion.

Comment: Telerik errors out, I think it can't handle the line ((IAddChild)page2Content).AddChild(page2);

Comment: Telerik is now working for me, strange.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What have you tried?

How about this...

```
Dim page2 As New FixedPage()
Dim page2Content As New PageContent()
DirectCast(page2Content, IAddChild).AddChild(page2)
```

Comment: @Jacoobley, that worked (need to wait 5 mins before I can accept your answer). Think the online converters were freaking out on the DirectCast bit.